# JSON.parse() javascript Unexpected token {

Tags: java, json

I get the following error:

```
undefined:2
{"data":{"my":88.43869018554688,"mx":-293.594970703125},"id":2}
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Socket.<anonymous>(/home/lchost/fishy.io/server/custom_modules/game.js:34:23)
```

my code on server:

```
socket.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
    var json = JSON.parse(data.toString());
    ...
```

code on android client:

```
public class TouchEventObject implements JSONable {

public float mx;
public float my;

public TouchEventObject(float mx, float my) {
    this.mx = mx;
    this.my = my;
}

@Override
public JSONObject toJSON() {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    try {
        json.put("mx", mx);
        json.put("my", my);
    } catch(Exception e) {};
    return json;
}
}
```

and:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if(world != null && me != null && canvas_width != -1 && canvas_height != -1) {
        Camera camera = Camera.getInstance();
        float x = camera.getX() <= 0 ? event.getX() - me.x*camera.getScale() : camera.getX() >= world.WIDTH - canvas_width ? ((world.WIDTH - canvas_width) + event.getX()) - me.x*camera.getScale() : event.getX() - canvas_width/2;
        float y = camera.getY() <= 0 ? event.getY() - me.y*camera.getScale() : camera.getY() >= world.HEIGHT - canvas_height ? ((world.HEIGHT - canvas_height) + event.getY()) - me.y*camera.getScale() : event.getY() - canvas_height/2;

        if (client != null && client.isConnected()) {
            JSONObject json = new TouchEventObject(x, y).toJSON();
            client.sendMessage(PacketType.MOUSEMOVE, json);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

any ideas what could cause the problem???
this is really strange because several times this doesn't throw an error but after 3 or 4 successfully handled socket transfers it does fail.
thank you in advance

Comment: Why would you tag it with [javascript]?..

Comment: JSON string + JSON string != valid JSON.  You can't just parse two JSON strings at once.

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(data.toString());`

Comment: 1. because the problem is with javascript part (Node JS server)
2. I don't understand what you mean, how could you solve it?
3. the output is:
`{"data":{"my":99.971923828125,"mx":-224.635498046875},"id":2}
{"data":{"my":97.59689331054688,"mx":-256.53271484375},"id":2}
{"data":{"my":96.31787109375,"mx":-263.279541015625},"id":2}
{"data":{"my":95.0263671875,"mx":-266.1590576171875},"id":2}
{"data":{"my":91.0035400390625,"mx":-283.5062255859375},"id":2}
{"data":{"my":88.43869018554688,"mx":-293.594970703125},"id":2}`
the problem is that 5 times before it parses well and then not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually @Mr. Llama was right. my code just sent two JSONs in one message... I've put `Thread.sleep(100)` into a code that handles touch event:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if(world != null && me != null && canvas_width != -1 && canvas_height != -1) {
        Camera camera = Camera.getInstance();
        float x = camera.getX() <= 0 ? event.getX() - me.x*camera.getScale() : camera.getX() >= world.WIDTH - canvas_width ? ((world.WIDTH - canvas_width) + event.getX()) - me.x*camera.getScale() : event.getX() - canvas_width/2;
        float y = camera.getY() <= 0 ? event.getY() - me.y*camera.getScale() : camera.getY() >= world.HEIGHT - canvas_height ? ((world.HEIGHT - canvas_height) + event.getY()) - me.y*camera.getScale() : event.getY() - canvas_height/2;

        if (client != null && client.isConnected()) {
            JSONObject json = new TouchEventObject(x, y).toJSON();
            client.sendMessage(PacketType.MOUSEMOVE, json);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch(Exception e) {}
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```